# apache poi XSSF Excel takes long time to open

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I'm using Apache poi 3.8 for reading xlsx file, it does everything correctly, but finally while opening the xlsx file, it takes long time.
First it creates a blank excel sheet and after some 5 mins it loads the data in the sheet.
But while using xls, it doesn't take such a long time, the file gets opened in few secs.

Can you please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with xml namespace resolution or schema validation? Is there a difference when you open it without being connected to the network?

Comment: Have you checked the other links on the stack-sites? [1](http://superuser.com/questions/447264/diagnosing-slow-excel-spreadsheets), [2](http://superuser.com/questions/247243/big-excel-file-freezing-running-slowly), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11967980/finding-out-why-excel-file-loads-slowly), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142917/one-of-my-excel-2010-file-very-slow-to-open)